# Why is this date sum not being displayed correctly in react?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following component which simply gets the current date, adds a year to it, and should render it. But its rendering a weird number

```
    import React from 'react'

class Calendario extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            birth_date : new Date(),
            years_to_live: 10,
            death_date: ""
        };

    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var death_date = this.state.birth_date.setFullYear(this.state.birth_date.getFullYear() + 1) //this is should result in the current date +1
        this.setState({ death_date : death_date});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p>Hello world!</p>
                <p>{this.state.death_date}</p>

            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Calendario;
```

It for some reason renders

```
1610227797517
```

Instead of

```
Sat Jan 09 2021 22:21:12 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

Whats the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting back a date as an integer, since you are using a javascript `Date` object for `birth_date`.

You can parse it back to a date to do what you need to (format, etc.)

```
var dt = new Date(1610227797517);
console.log(dt);
// output: Sat Jan 09 2021 16:29:57 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

But, you should be able to use a format on the object itself

```
console.log(this.state.death_date.toDateString());
// output: Sat Jan 09 2021
```